# Is a non Jew allowed to wear the tablets of the 10 commandments as a necklace?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, jewelry, aseres-hadibros

Is a non Jew allowed to wear the tablets of the 10 commandments as a necklace?

I am sking this question because I heard that a non Jew is not allowed to wear a mezuza as a necklace even if it is not a real mezuza.

Comment: I can't see why not, but as I am no expert and have no proof, I will resist answering authoritatively. Do you have any reason to think that Judaism limits how a non-Jew dresses or how a non-Jew crafts jewelry?

Comment: A better way of asking this might be something along the lines of "Would it be culturally appropriate for a non-Jew to wear a necklace with Jewish iconography such as the Ten Commandments?" or a simpler restatement of the above.

Comment: If you're discussing this within the context of Jewish law, or for that matter Noahide law, the only problem I could see is if the inscription of the 10 commandments uses the 4-letter name of G-d. Even Noahides have an obligation not to desecrate G-d's name. Thus, PERHAPS, there may be a problem with wearing this type of necklace while in a bathroom or if it falls & someone steps on it. I'd have to research that angle a bit further. However, please edit your question so that we understand its focus.

Comment: "Allowed to"?  By whose rules?

Comment: I edited the question and said what is the purpose of it

Comment: Within the context of what you mentioned, it seems that Ramba"m, in particular, was against Jews wearing any form of amulet, b/c people considered them supertisious. I don't know if Ramba"m addresses this same prohibition for non-Jews. But, I'm curious if this is where you had heard this idea?

Comment: @DanF well, Rabbi Hayim Halevi Donin says in his book "To Be a Jew" that any Jew can wear a mezuza as long he or she doesn;t wear it as a charm even if it not kosher. I've heard from other source (I forgot where) that a gentile is forbidden to wear a mezuzah, I don't know if it applies to the tablets too

Comment: @mil maybe you heard about tzitis that it is forbidden to sell a goy (since people will think he is Jewish), is there not a story in the gemoro when a Rabbi gives a gentile a mezzuza

Answer (score -1):

I viewed [this wiki article](http://www.wikinoah.org/index.php?title=Optional_observances_for_non-Jews) which presents various viewpoints on not just the mezuzah issue but the concept of Noahides performing Jewish mitzvoth. While there are various viewpoints, there is a common denominator regarding the mezuzah.

The prohibition is that Noahides are forbidden from affixing a kosher (real) mezuzah to their doorposts. There is nothing stated about wearing a kosher mezuzah as a necklace, though, I could see some problems for even a Jew doing this, as it has G-d's name in it and could be treated improperly or disrespectfully. Thus, a similar problem would occur if the 10 commandments charm uses the 4-letter name of G-d (or any Hebrew written name of G-d) on it, as even Noahides are commanded not to desecrate G-d's name.

Beyond that, if it is neither a real mezuzah or the symbol of the 10 Commandment tablets with, say, no "inscription" or not having G-d's name, I can't see that as problematic.

As far as possible concerns of *mar'it ayin* (loosely translated as other people who see this will assume your violating a prohibition), I think these days, the majority of the public is accustomed to people wearing various charms as a necklace. Certainly, regarding the 10 commandments, no one will think that they are the "real" thing, anyway, b/c a real Torah wouldn't fit around your neck!

To verify all this, speak to a competent rabbi.

Comment: Could you cite the prohibition? The only thing I've ever found is that the Radbaz was choichech/deliberated on the matter of tefillin, mezuzot, and scrolls.

Comment: I believe that the linked article cites Rambam. Inform me if not.

Comment: No where in Rambam does it say Bnei Noach cannot do Mitzvot. Hilchot Melachim 10:10 says that they may do any if performed properly.